# Equality on sum of squares constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, sums-of-squares, non-convex-optimization

I've been working on an optimization problem that is almost a semi-definite program (SDP) barring a sum of squares constraint (expressed as under) which is making it a non-convex problem:
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{i,j}x_{ij}^2 = 1   
\end{equation}

As a preliminary approach to solving this, we can re-write the above constraint in the equivalent form:
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{i,j}x_{ij}^2 \leq 1 \\
    \sum_{i,j}x_{ij}^2 \geq 1 
\end{equation}
and then approximate the second constraint i.e. $\sum_{i,j}x_{ij}^2 \geq 1$ in some way that lower bounds the absolute values $|x_{ij}|$.

Again, as the right lower bounds on $|x_{ij}|$ are difficult to figure, is there any possible work around to solve the main problem with or without using the idea presented above (even an approximate solution is fine)?

A few points to be noted:

1. Relaxing the constraint isn't giving anything useful in my particular case.
2. The main constraint i.e. $\sum_{i,j}x_{ij}^2 = 1$ is an equivalent replacement for a relatively intractable constraint $\text{rank}(X) = 1$ as the sum-of-squares form looked a tad more tractable but an approach in either of these two directions should be fine.
3. Trying to avoid black-box optimization techniques such as genetic algorithm, simulated annealing so a classical approach would be the suit best here.

Comment: Which function do you wish to maximise / minimise?

Comment: @user7427029: The objective is some linear function.

Comment: @AkshayBansal If the objective is a linear function, there exists closed form solution for minimum and maximum given this constraint. We don't need optimisation.

Comment: @NN2: This is not the only constraint in the problem. The full problem is a semi-definite program with other LMI constraints too.

Comment: What do you mean by the notation
$\quad\sum_\limits{ij} x_{ij}?\quad$
Do you mean $\quad \sum_\limits{i=1}^j x_i\quad$ which is the sum of $\space i^{th}\space$ x's from $1$-to-$j$?

Comment: @poetasis: It means summation over both $i,j$ i.e. $\sum_i  \sum_j x_{ij}$.